# Como resolver esse problema na colisão?

Tags: javascript, css, html5, css3, animação

Se eu verifico a colisão só na horizontal, o programa pega toda a largura do cenário e não só da div.

**Código:**

```
<html>
<style>
#dv{

border:1px solid red;
background-color:#344;
height:80px;
position:absolute;
}
#dv2{

border:1px solid black;
background-color:#f00;
height:80px;
position:absolute;

}




</style>
<body>
<div id = "dv"></div>
<div id = "dv2"></div>
<script>
var valor = 0;
var valor2 = 180;
var dv= document.getElementById("dv");
var div2 = document.getElementById("dv2");

var largura = dv.style.width = 80;
var lateral = div2.style.left = 180;
var largura2 = div2.style.width = 80;
var lateral2 = div2.style.top = 300;

function moverDiv(){
valor += 5;
dv.style.left = valor+"px";


if(valor+largura > lateral){
div2.style.backgroundColor = "blue";


}
}
dv.addEventListener("touchmove",moverDiv);





</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Execução:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

A colisão entre quadrados e rectângulos ocorre quando o `left` (coordenada onde começa a ser desenhado) do *objecto A* for menor que o `left` mais o `width` (largura) do *objecto B* e o `left` mais o `width` do *objecto A* for maior que o `left` do *objecto B* e o mesmo com `top` e `height`.

```
if (A.x < B.x + B.w && A.x + A.w > B.x) {
     if (A.y < B.y + B.h && A.h + A.y > B.y) {
         // Está colidindo
     }
}
```

O `x` é o `left`, e o `w` é o `width`. Se tiver acesso ao à propriedade `right`, este equivale à soma do `left` com o `width`, e `bottom` equivale à some de `top` e `height`

No seu exemplo você também não está a setar de volta a cor vermelha quando já não há colisão...

Veja este exemplo no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vsr6L93e/)

Comment: blz,mas o grande caso mesmo é que a div preta está acima da div vermelha e mesmo assim quando eu passo pro lado ele indentificar que colidiu.

Comment: @DaniloSantos tem que fazer o mesmo para o eixo do y (vertical), veja exemplo do link

Comment: Ok vou tentar isso

Comment: Assim ele verifica y e não x e o caminho fica aberto para usar as duas  coordenadas intendi.por isso usar as duas cordenadas.

Comment: Muito obrigado VIK